# Existence of a Lebesgue measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The following is from Carother's Real Analysis:

> Suppose that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable with $m(E)=1$. Show that there is a measurable set $F\subset E: m(F)=1/2$.

Carothers offers a hint which says to consider $f(x)=m(E\cap (-\infty,x])$, but I don't see how to apply this. Could I please get a hint to get me on the right track?

My confusion lies in this: If the limit is approaching positive infinity, then we are making $(-\infty,x]$ very big but at the very least we know that the measure of $E$ is 1, so this means that the $(-\infty,\infty)$ interval is small or else the measure of its intersection would just be the measure of $E$ which is one. So why is it zero?

Comment: $f$ is continuous, and its limits at $\pm \infty$ are $0$ and $1$. Now, use IVT.

Comment: Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose without loss of generality that $x\leq y$. Then $|f(y)-f(x)|=f(y)-f(x)=m(E\cap (x,y])\leq y-x =|y-x|$. So $f$ is continuous. Since $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=0$ and  $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=1$, there is $a \in  \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a) =1/2$. That means, $m(E\cap (-\infty, a])=1/2$. Take $F= E\cap (-\infty, a]$.

Comment: @Crostul: Why are its limits $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Regarding your question to @Ramiro, use $\epsilon = \delta$ in an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. In fact, the inequality shows that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant equal to $1.$

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general; for a counterexample, let $m$ be the Dirac measure $\delta_0$. Then for any measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ containing 0, we have $m(E) = 1$, but there is no measurable set with measure $1/2$.

If however you assue $m$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, then $f$ will be a continuous function, and you can apply IVT to obtain $F$.

Comment: Yes, I am dealing with the Lebesgue measure in this particular case. However, I am missing why the function is continuous?

Comment: You could update your question to make it clear that $m$ represents Lebesgue measure. @Ramiro 's comment gives a proof of continuity of $f$ - it demonstrates that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x-y|$, so using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, if we pick $\epsilon >0$, we can take $\delta = \epsilon$ and we obtain that given $x \in\mathbb{R}$, if we take $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$, so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I've clearly been awake for too long. How did I not notice that? Yes, thanks, I've updated the question to specify the Lebesgue measure